# Elasticsearch sorting with specific importance for field values

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am using Java and Spring data, Elasticsearch 6.8.14 Api. to communicate with Elasticsearch. I have index that returns such data (I am including this search result to show the mapping structure also)

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "rgt",
        "_type" : "carindexeddata",
        "_id" : "6020354",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "4441",
          "version" : null,
          "carId" : "1263",
          "mark" : "ford",
          "colour" : "green",
          "status" : "Approved",
        
......
```

So basically I store cars. Now I need to sort them before returning to the user. I have to sort it:

```
 - mark
 - colour (within same mark colours are important)
 - status
```

And as for the status the sort order should be as follows:

```
1. BOUGHT
2. IN PRODUCTION
3. IN TESTS
4. APPROVED
```

So having such cars order would be OK:

```
1. Ford Black Bought
2. Ford Black Approved
3. Ford White Bought
4. GMC White Bought
5. GMC White Approved
```

Which mechanism in Elasticsearch could I use to sort items that way ? Is it possible to implement? Can u show some example ? Sorting by fields mark, colour, status is not correct because there is some custom logic in status sorting - it is not letter sorting but some weight sorting I would say.. but how to give specific weights for specific statuses in elasticesearch? Should I store a field with some number for each status in Elastic search and sort according to this number field instead status field directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For status field, you can use [script sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-sort-context.html)

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "mark.keyword": "asc",
      "colour.keyword": "asc",
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
                    if(doc['status.keyword'].value.toUpperCase()=="BOUGHT")
                            return 1;
                    else if(doc['status.keyword'].value.toUpperCase()=="IN PRODUCTION")
                            return 2;
                    else if(doc['status.keyword'].value.toUpperCase()=="IN TESTS")
                            return 3;
                    else return 4;
                    """
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Scripts are slow.

Elastic search works best when data is preprocessed. If you can have a numeric field which represents status value, performance will be better. You need to check it out what works best for your case.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there is script sorting in ES. Hovewer I forgot to mention that I use spring data for ES integration in Java. Is there any object approach (with usage of elasticsearch Java API or spring data) to do such search and then is it still valid to use script approach ? I noticed QueryBuilders.customFiltersScoreQuery(qb).add(FilterBuilders.termFilter("ln",
someValue_2), 100); example on the net but by QueryBuilders donesnt containt customFiltersScoreQuerymethod. I use ES 6.8.14 api.

Comment: @Frankio1 I am not familiar with spring-data ,  I did a quick search and found this example  Script script = new Script( "doc.count.value <= 0 ? doc.visitor.value : doc.visitor.value * doc.count.value");
SortBuilders.scriptSort(script, ScriptSortType.NUMBER).order(SortOrder.DESC);

Comment: @Frankio1 For your question "Should I store a field with some number for each status in Elastic search and sort according to this number field instead status field directly ?" I have updated in answer

Answer (score 0):

The source should be a string for better performance and the language used behind the elastic sort script is Groovy.

```
{
  "mark.keyword": "asc",
  "colour.keyword": "asc",
  "_script": {
    "type": "number",
    "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "source": "if(doc['status.keyword'].value.toUpperCase()=='BOUGHT') return 1 else if(doc['status.keyword'].value.toUpperCase()=='IN PRODUCTION') return 2 else if(doc['status.keyword'].value.toUpperCase()=='IN TESTS') return 3 else return 4"
    },
    "order": "asc"
  }
}
```